# How do I make no replacement matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

```
    z1  z2
Z1= z11 z12
    z21 z22
    z31 z32
```

Use Z1 matrix, I want to make new ZZ matrix like this

```
       zz1      zz2      zz3      zz4
 ZZ= z11*z11  z11*z12  z12*z11  z12*z12
     z21*z21  z21*z22  z22*z21  z12*z12
     z31*z31  z31*z32  z32*z31  z12*z12
```

How do I make ZZ matrix in R? I try for() function but I'm fail...

Comment: as a startingpoint you can try `a <- matrix(1:12, 6, 2);
cbind(a[,1]*a[,1], a[,1]*a[,2], a[,2]*a[,1], a[,2]*a[,3])`

Answer (score 1):

```
Z1 <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 2)

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    3    6

cbind(Z1[,1]*Z1[, c(1, 2, 2)], Z1[1, 2]^2)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    4   16
# [2,]    4   10   10   16
# [3,]    9   18   18   16
```